# How to do a single pass with badblocks in destructive mode?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, bad-sectors

I am using [badblocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badblocks) to do a destructive erase of any data on the disk; using the following command:

`badblocks -wsp 0 /dev/sdb1`

I passed the option `-p 0` in the hopes that this would result in only a single pass, but I am getting multiple passes:

```
Testing with pattern 0xaa: done
Reading and comparing: done
Testing with pattern 0x55: done
Reading and comparing: done
Testing with pattern 0xff: done
Reading and comparing: 19.01% done, 7:43:47 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)
```

From reading the manpage, I can see that the `-w` option itself includes four passes:

> -w Use write-mode test. With this option, badblocks scans for bad blocks by writing some patterns (0xaa, 0x55, 0xff, 0x00) on every
> block of the device, reading every block and comparing the contents.
> This option may not be combined with the -n option, as they are
> mutually exclusive.

This is excessive for my needs. Is there any way to achieve a single destructive pass?

Comment: Keep in mind, that the multiple passes are not for erasing the data. They are **necessary** to find certain errors on your disk. Otherwise you might not find all bad blocks. Consider the case where a bit is always stuck at `1`. If you only did test with the `0xff`-pattern, you would not be able to find this error. Since `badblocks` is not designed to erase the data, but to find bad blocks, multiple passes is not considered to be excessive.

Comment: @Slizzered Thanks, that's useful to consider. Shouldn't two passes be sufficient in that case? 0xff and 0x00.

Comment: @Slizzered Thinking about it, I suppose that wouldn't cover the case where writing a 1 would fail, but the bit already has a 1, but I can't think of a scenario where 3 passes would be insufficient (0xff, 0x00, 0xff again)

Comment: Actually you got it a bit wrong, I think. Writing itself can not be checked against failure. It writes `0xff` and immediately checks if there is `0xff` written by *reading* the location from disk. So the *stuck 0* is ruled out. Then, it does the same with `0x00` to rule out the *stuck 1* error. so 1 pass with each pattern is sufficient. The other ones (alternating pattern of `0` and `1`) are against bits that *stick together* (if I set bit N to `1`, bit N+1 also goes to `1` as a result of the error)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Upon reading the manpage further, I've solved the problem. `-w` does indeed do a single pass, as implied from the description of the `-p` option:

> Default is 0, meaning badblocks will exit after the first pass.

A pass consists of four test patterns:

> -w Use  write-mode  test. With this option, badblocks scans for bad blocks by writing some patterns  (0xaa,  0x55,  0xff,  0x00) on every
> block of the device, reading every block and comparing the contents.

The pattern can be overriden using the `-t` option:

> -t test_pattern Specify a test pattern to be read (and written) to disk blocks. The  test_pattern may  either  be  a  numeric  value
> between 0 and ULONG_MAX-1 inclusive, or the word "random", which
> specifies that the block should be filled with a  random  bit
> pattern.   For  read/write  (-w) and non-destructive (-n) modes, one
> or more test patterns may be specified by specifying the -t option for
> each test  pattern  desired. For  read-only  mode only a single
> pattern may be specified and it may not be "random". Read-only testing
> with a pattern assumes that the specified pattern has previously been
> written to the disk - if not, large numbers of blocks will fail
> verification.  If multiple patterns are specified then all blocks will
> be tested with one pattern before proceeding to the next pattern.

---

Example command and output:

```
# badblocks -wsvt 0 /dev/sdz
Checking for bad blocks in read-write mode
From block 0 to 488386583
Testing with pattern 0x00: done                                                 
Reading and comparing: done                                                 
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)
```

Comment: I don't get it. What about the entire discussion you had in the comments with @Slizzered? 

I think the most reasonable flags to use are `-wsv` (taking the `-t 0` out from your answer here). 

I agree that 4 entire passes is a long time to wait and we often don't have that long to wait (my 14TB drives would take 72 hrs). And maybe most issues if there are issues will crop up within the first test. But it's really supposed to do a full pass of all 4 of those patterns... that's what the answer should be. I guess it's subjective because the meaning of "pass" is kind of up for debate here.

Comment: Keep in mind you can run badblocks in parallel. So if you had 10 of these drives to check you could do a full check on them in the ~72 hours instead of the unacceptable quantity of time that would be 720 hours (30 days).

Comment: @StevenLu Thanks for spotting that. Actually it was my question that was at fault rather than my answer. My aim when I wrote this was to destroy the data rather than check for errors. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense then. I do believe though for a really secure erase you'll also need multiple passes, I suppose letting it do all 4 passes ought to accomplish that well.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal was to destroy the data rather than looking for errors, then you could just use

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX status=progress
```

where X is the letter of your target device.

But if you are really worried about the data on your disk, you can run dd multiple times, use other tools like wipe or shred or just let badblocks do its job. It all depends on the time you are willing to invest in deleting the data.